# Why it isn't possible to query demographic criteria with session id and client id?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am using Query explorer: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

This is what I tried:
[image]

It gives me 0 results but when I remove dimension4 which is sessionclientid the result is over 1000.

The dimension4 doesn't seem to work well with userGender. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only going to get results where dimension4 was set.  If you haven't sent data with all of your hits for dimension4 then your not going to get any results. 
In the event that a dimension value is null Google analytics will not return it.  Make sure you are setting that with all of the hits you are sending.

Remember that old hits those before you added the dimension custom dimension will not contain the dimension and there for not be returned.

There are also a number of dimensions that simply cant be associated with each other because the data doesn't exist.  This happends a lot with custom dimensions.

Comment: I do not understand.

Comment: There is no data in dimension4 it wont return the row.  Google analytics wont return a row that has a null dimension.   Not sure how to explain it better than that.

Comment: Hey I just now finished studying this and talked with the guy on my team who setup dimension4. 

Dimension 4 definitely has data into it, it's a custom dimension that is set on the session level (not the hit level), and is applied to all users (it assigns a unique ID to every device visiting our website).

Perhaps if the custom dimension was set on a user-level rather then a session level?

Comment: or perhaps demographic data isn't available for custom dimensions as this is internal Google data.